# broken pipe on ssh during connection

Tags: ssh, fedora

Using fedora 24, I have ssh connection problem. I installed it on 2 laptops and have the same problem on both. When I ssh, it asks for a password during connection, but immediately writes broken pipe and kicks me out.

```
ssh -l myname 192.168.1.5
myname@192.168.1.5's password:
packet_write_wait: Connection to 192.168.1.5 port 22: Broken pipe
```

When I make it verbose, I have this:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: password
myname@192.168.1.5's password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 192.168.1.5 ([192.168.1.5]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
packet_write_wait: Connection to 192.168.1.5 port 22: Broken pipe
```

I have no idea of how to connect, but I can connect from the same laptop to another debian laptop. I cannot connect from debian to any of those 2 Fedora computers.

I tried `ssh -l myname localhost` twice then ran `journalctl -u sshd` and this is the result:

```
Nov 03 17:15:09 localhost.localdomain sshd[15663]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Nov 03 17:15:09 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started OpenSSH server daemon.
Nov 03 17:19:37 localhost.localdomain sshd[16025]: Accepted password for myname from 127.0.0.1 port 57942 ssh2
Nov 03 17:22:50 localhost.localdomain sshd[16086]: Accepted password for myname from 127.0.0.1 port 57996 ssh2
```

I don't know where to find more logs.

PS: SElinux is disabled.

I tried 2 times `ssh -l myname localhost` then run `journalctl -u sshd` and this is the result:

```
Nov 03 17:15:09 localhost.localdomain sshd[15663]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Nov 03 17:15:09 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started OpenSSH server daemon.
Nov 03 17:19:37 localhost.localdomain sshd[16025]: Accepted password for myname from 127.0.0.1 port 57942 ssh2
Nov 03 17:22:50 localhost.localdomain sshd[16086]: Accepted password for myname from 127.0.0.1 port 57996 ssh2
```

Comment: You need to look in the target machine's log files to see why `ssh` is rejecting your incoming connections.

Comment: See ["Write Failed: Broken Pipe” when trying to login through ssh with a specific user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220104/write-failed-broken-pipe-when-trying-to-login-through-ssh-with-a-specific-use)

Comment: As noted on the earlier stackoverflow post, we need the logs from the server to make sense of this.

Comment: Did you set up a user `myname` on that hosts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Change value of **UsePrivilegeSeparation** into **yes**.

I using fedora23, and I met the same with you, try my solution above, maybe it works. It looks like a problem about **openssh-server-7.2p2-1**.