# SSH on Debian "Buster" reports broken pipe after authentication

Tags: debian, ssh, authentication

I have already set the following in /etc/ssh/ssh_config

```
Host *
ServerAliveInterval 100
```

and the following in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
ClientAliveInterval 100
ClientAliveCountMax 3
```

The following is the log of ssh after entering password.

```
root@localhost's password: 
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to localhost ([127.0.0.1]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: send packet: type 1
packet_write_wait: Connection to 127.0.0.1 port 22: Broken pipe
```

Comment: Can you test it by another host over the network?

Comment: Yes. I have tested it using PuTTy over our local LAN. But it doesn't seem to work there too. The connection is abruptly closed without any useful logs on the client-side.

Comment: By "The connection is abruptly closed without any useful logs on the client-side.", I guess the port 22 is closed. Can you check port 22 of this host from another host over the LAN?

Comment: I meant to say the connection is abruptly closed after authentication.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [broken pipe on ssh during connection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320691/broken-pipe-on-ssh-during-connection)

Comment: No. I tried setting both "UsePrivilegeSeparation" (deprecated) and "SANDBOX" to yes. But the problem persisted.

Comment: Alright, it's weird. Try to do a fresh install of SSH.